# How can I insert an array of data into a SQL Server database using sequelize in node js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables `asssessment` and `questions` and I want to insert some questions from `questions` table into the assessment table for single assessment table so I have an array of questions and I want to insert those into the assessment table for single assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Using only those two tables doesn't sound like a good approach. It violates the relational model of a database.

You might want to use the following approach:

Table [asssessment]: main description of the assessment itself, one row per assessment, Primary key for instance asssessment_ID.

Table [questions]: the curent table that you have, hopefully with a primary key column such as question_ID.

Table [asssessment_questions]: With a separate Primary key column, a column [asssessment_ID] with a foreign key reference to the [asssessment] table, and a column [question_ID] with a foreign key reference to the [questions] table.

Then you could add a [persons] table to store data about people doing the asssessment and link this table to the [asssessment] table with an intermediate table similar to [asssessment_questions].

As a next step you might want to collect information how an individual person did answer a specific question in a specific asssessment. This could be done with another table similar to [asssessment_questions], but based on [asssessment_questions] and [persons].

Answer (score -1):

You can insert array in database using sequelize. You want to change in model like below. I am trying to add multiple languages in database through array.

```
language: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        get() {
            return this.getDataValue('language').split(';')
        },
        set(val)            
          {
           this.setDataValue('language',Array.isArray(val) ? val.join(','):val);

      }
  },
```